# if a company rewards the use of software, which license should apply?

Tags: copyright, license

I need to develop free software for a company. The company will reward me with 8% of the profits. I have to give the source code to the company so that they can modify it if necessary. Is there a license that protects me in case they reuse my source code to build a new application and I no longer get 8%?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure your concern can be covered by a copyright license. There certainly isn't an open-source license that covers monetary compensation. I would advise you to settle this in a contract between you and the company and to have that looked over by a lawyer if you wish.

Comment: I think that open source does not mean free software... maybe there exists a license that can help me

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/open-source-but-not-free-software-or-vice-versa

Comment: Open source does indeed not preclude getting money in return for providing the software. But your concern for receiving a percentage of profits goes beyond what you can arrange with a copyright license, open-source or not.

Comment: The question is problematic because you fail to clearly distinguish the 4 relevant parties: A, yourself. B, the company which pays you (A) 8%. C, end users and D, users which use their free software rights to redistribute the source. You know see that the problem is that you get 8% of the money that B makes of user groups C and D, but users in groups C and D can also get the software for free from other users in D instead of getting it from B. The director of B can in fact sell the software to himself and then give it away from free. Microsoft pulled this trick with Mosaic, now known as IE.

Comment: @dbusc Open Source software is almost always Free Software and vica versa. It is hard to find a licence that is one and not the other (according to definition). However the free-software-foundation, and the open-source-institute do not always agree.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it doesn't relate to free / open source software *within the site's definition*.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a license that protects me in case they reuse my source code to build a new application and I no longer get 8%?

By accepted definition on https://opensource.org/licenses such a license won't be open source (or [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), e.g. [GPLv3+](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html) software).

I am not a  lawyer. You need to pay one.

Read a paper on [*Simple Economics of open source*](https://www.nber.org/papers/w7600)  ([one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Tirole) of the authors had a Nobel prize in economics)

Answer (score -2):

You are writing the software under contract with the company, so the rights aren't yours to begin with...

Comment: Wrong. It depends on the terms, and on the local laws.

Comment: I am paid to write GPLv3+ software. Indirectly by the European taxpayer (thru H2020 projects) and directly by my employer [CEA](https://www.cea.fr/). Copyright belongs to CEA (or to the FSF for contributions to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), moral rights to me.